# Eager loading include with using UseLazyLoadingProxies

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, lazy-loading, ef-core-2.2

I am creating the db connection like so:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionbuilder)
{
    optionbuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlite(@"Data Source=Data.db");
}
```

And I am trying to access an object like so:

```
public static User GetProfile(int uid)
{
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        return db.Users.Include(x => x.Settings).FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == uid);
    }
}
```

The user object is as follows:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUsed{ get; set; }

    public virtual Setting Settings { get; set; }
}
```

but upon accessing `Users.Settings`, it throws the following error:

> 'Error generated for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning:
>   An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'Settings' on
>   entity type 'UserProxy' after the associated DbContext was disposed.'.
>   This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID
>   'CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning' to the
>   'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
>   'AddDbContext'.'

I understand what this means but it goes against my understanding of includes and how it causes eager loading.

My understanding was that when using an `include` and accessing the object explicitly by calling `FirstOrDefault` eager load the related objects to be populated immediately without the need for the db connection to remain open; but apparently, this is not the case.

What would be the right way to do this without requiring the database be left open?

Comment: Does `db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == uid);` works as expected?

Comment: Yes, it loads all directly related properties fine, it's only when I try to access `.Settings` after the include, the exception is thrown.

Comment: Okay! Does `db.Users.Include(x => x.Settings).FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == uid);` work as expected while `UseLazyLoadingProxies()` is removed?

Comment: Yup! Eager loading works fine without the declaration of `UseLazyLoadingProxies()`.

Comment: Its seems a bug in EF Core, You can post the problem here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues

Comment: Hey, thanks, I posted an issue, here is the link for posterity sake: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15170
I will, however, return when the issue is resolved either way.

Comment: The sql/logs being generated before the exception being thrown would be helpful

Comment: Probably related to this v3 fix https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#lazy-loading-proxies-no-longer-assume-navigation-properties-are-fully-loaded

Comment: Ivan, it sounds like you may be right! Their description of the issue fits exactly to my use case. I will attempt to use 3.0 RC4 and see if this solves the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auther V, a developer working on EFC has confirmed that this is a bug.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15170

[Documentation about this change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#lazy-loading-proxies-no-longer-assume-navigation-properties-are-fully-loaded)

It is fixed in EF Core 3.0.0 RC4 but as of writing this, is not available in the public domain. I personally would not suggest using RC4 as it is still in development and is not well suited for general purpose or production use.

For now, you can suppress the error like so:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionbuilder)
{
    optionbuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=Data.db").UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    optionbuilder.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning));
}
```

The `optionbuilder.ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Ignore(CoreEventId.LazyLoadOnDisposedContextWarning));` line is what you'd need.

But please be aware that any improper usage of lazy loading will also be ignored providing nulled variants when object traveseral is attempted for closed DBContext instances.