# Include property of each item in a collection in EF Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .Net Core 2.2 project with EntityFramework and a model with many nested properties either single object or collections.

I've enabled lazy loading and now I want selectively load only the parts of the object tree I'm insterested in in my controller.

When I use .Include() everything is fine until I want to include a collection property and for every item in that collection I want to include a related entity.

Reading the documentation I used this approach:

```
var mainObj = _db.MyEntityA.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(e => e.MyEntityB)
            .Include(e => e.CollectionOfEntityC.Select((MyEntityC ce) => ce.MyEntityD))
```

When I run it it gives something like this:

```
InvalidOperationException: The Include property lambda expression 'e => {from EntityC ce in e.CollectionOfEntityC select [ce].MyEntityD}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'.
```

So I've tried to add the cast:

```
var mainObj = _db.MyEntityA.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(e => e.MyEntityB)
            .Include(e => e.CollectionOfEntityC.Select((MyEntityC ce) => ce.MyEntityD))
```

But nothing changes.

I've tried to use .ThenInclude() this way:

```
    var mainObj = _db.MyEntityA.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(e => e.MyEntityB)
            .ThenInclude(e => e.Select((MyEntityC ce) => ce.MyEntityD))
```

With or without the cast, nothing changes.

Finally, reasonably, if I remove that navigation property, it gives me this exception:

```
Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning: An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'MyEntityD' on detached entity of type 'MyEntityCProxy'. Lazy-loading is not supported for detached entities or entities that are loaded with 'AsNoTracking()'.
```

This same scenario, worked as expected on the EF for the .Net Framework, form which I'm porting to .Net Core.

**EDIT:**

Exploring the correctly mentioned duplicates, I just wanted to add few more related aspects.

@StriplingWarrior answer below is good; I fixed my code using .ThenInclude() instead of .Select(); now everything builds, but:

- IntelliSense doesn't help writing the code inside ThenInclude()
- if I leave `AsNoTraking()` I must disable the `DetachedLazyLoadingWarning`
- if I remove `AsNoTracking()` EF tracks changes I don't want it to track (I want a readonly snapshot of a complex object)

Comment: [Loading Related Data - Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels), e.g. `.Include(e => e.CollectionOfEntityC).ThenInclude(ce  => ce.MyEntityD)`.

Comment: Your edit has noting to do with the original question, which *is* a duplicate simply due to invalid `Include` / `ThenInclude` usage. What about the new issue, first is should have been a separate post, and second is duplicate of the EF Core bug asked and answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369146/eager-loading-include-with-using-uselazyloadingproxies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It looks like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#including-multiple-levels) this is how you're supposed to use `ThenInclude`:

```
var mainObj = _db.MyEntityA.AsNoTracking()
        .Include(e => e.MyEntityB)
        .Include(e => e.CollectionOfEntityC)
        .ThenInclude(ce => ce.MyEntityD);
```

Comment: You're right, and coming from EF6 I didn't figure this properly. I've seen duplicates and now it's almost all clear. But I have new issues, maybe you can help: your first option doesn't work but the second does, but only if I disable warning (if I leave AsNoTracking() on) and in any case, every MyEntityD in the result is null.

Comment: @AndreaColleoni: After reading the message again I realized my first option was wrong: it would be for when you're using inheritance. I removed it from my answer. If the warning you had to disable is the one mentioned in the link I provided then that's not surprising: it sounds like they have a known issue with Roslyn. WRT MyEntityD being null in the result, I don't think I can help you figure that one out. Maybe you can create a new question showing your mapping and the data? You could also check the ToString() on your query to see how it's trying to get the MyEntityD data.

Comment: Your help was really precious. I debugged my query and found the issue. I was ThenIncluding an entity only once but i needed two! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.